# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad _alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc in c++

Tags: c++, stl

```
typedef struct abc{
    vector<int> path;
    int cost;
}nodetype;

vector<nodetype> population;

nodetype find_child(int rno)     
{
    vector<nodetype>::iterator it;
    nodetype retval;
    int total=0;
    for(it=population.begin(); it!= population.end() ; it++)
    {
        total= total+ (*it).cost;
        if(total>=rno)
        {
            retval = (*it);    
            break;
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
int main()
{
    vector<nodetype> :: iterator it;
    int total=0;
    for(it=population.begin();it!=population.end();it++)
    {
        total= total + (*it).cost;
    }
    //population vector is filled . So the total is not zero
   cin>>rno
    nodetype parent1= find_child(rno+1);     //1st call
    cin>>rno; 
    nodetype parent2= find_child(rno+1);    //2nd call
}
```

Population is the vector of nodetype,which is defined above.In 1st call, the program doesn't crash.It successfully calls the find_child() function ,adds up the population cost till it passes or equals the rno passed as an argument. But in the 2nd call, it calls the find_child() function and also enters the if condition given in function but the moment it executes the line " **retval= (*it)**", it crashes with given statement printed in the console "**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'  what():  std::bad_alloc**". Help me out.

PS:- I have been debugging my program, everything is declared and initialized properly. The problem comes when that statement inside if condition is executed.That too it works fine in 1st call, but crashes when the function is called 2nd time.

Comment: where is rno defined?

Comment: Welcome...and good to give an example.  But are we to believe that randomness has anything to do with it?  Can you cause the crash using just fixed numbers? (e.g. printing out what the random numbers were when they substituted to cause the problem)?  Can you cause the crash in question with less code still?  See the remarks in [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).  Note also that having the needed `#include`s and `using`s saves time...make sure people can paste in something like [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) etc. to demo your problems!  See EDIT button...

Comment: your vector is empty. What is `x % 0`?

Comment: @HostileFork   I have run the program with the fixed nos instead of generating random nos, still the same problem.  ;-(

Comment: @harshitmodani Well...consider the advice.  When I told you that using a random number generator has nothing to do with the problem, that's a hint to edit the post so that there's no call to rand() in it.  Unless your problem is explicitly about [random number generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) and why you're not getting the probability distribution you expect...then a call to rand() is *exactly what you need to EDIT out of your question*.  :-)  I gave you one link to read top to bottom already, here's a shorter one: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @HostileFork sorry for that..I am new to stack overflow,but I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing by zero. Your `vector<nodetype> population;` is never populated, so after this cycle, `total` is still `0`:

```
for(it=population.begin();it!=population.end();it++)
{
    total= total + (*it).cost;
}
```

And in this line, you divide some random number by that zero:

```
rno= rand() % total;
```

Comment: I'm betting there's a "Oh but I fill the vector in my real code" comment coming up soon.

Comment: @juanchopanza, may be. \*suspense intensifies\*

Comment: @SingerofTheFall I have fill the vector in my real code.

Comment: @juanchopanza, there you go.

Comment: I have rewritten the same code from scratch and its working this time.still haven't catch the bug in my previous code.But thanks for the help.